# Android App not updating automatically on user's device even marked as "Auto Update"

Tags: android, shopping-cart

I Have developed one android app for display daily promotional offers in different categories. Like Supermarket, electronics, fashion, hotels..etc. So I have to update and change the images frequently (like daily). 
At the moment, I do always change version code and do full roll out and release new version to the production. 
Is there any easy way to do this task..?
And it is not updating in user's device automatically (even though they have marked it as "Auto Update")
I am new to android can someone help on this matter...?

Comment: is the version which is not updated deployed to the device from android studio?

Comment: You really should be looking at another way of updating the images instead of updating the app every day.

Comment: Yes. Deployed from android studio and released from google developer console. But I have seen similar kind of apps updating frequently.

Comment: @Steve M - Of course... I wanna know which way is it..? I just wanna update images only.. May be i am using a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy your app from AndroidStudio the update mechanism is not working anymore. Only when you deploy(download and install) from GooglePlay the autoupdate is working